# jQuery Plugin Development - passing parameters to user defined callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thank you all ahead of time. This is my first time developing a jQuery plugin (and first time developing in javascript as well actually), and I have to say I'm pretty geeked (It probably has many hideous things to you seasoned js/jquery developers, but this is my first attempt - please bear with me :). I welcome any constructive criticism of any of the code too.

This is a model box plugin (yes, there are others, but job requirements dictate that I code my own to avoid third-party dependency) that displays text given, text from an ajax call, or  a form given/taken from an ajax call and then handles the form submission via ajax. This needs to be as customizable as possible, so I am attemping to provide some hooks ( ?? - anonymous functions ) the user can use to pass custom code to the plugin.

The problem I am having is providing parameters to the user function. If I use the keyword 'this', I can pass the 'msg' variable fine and the user function can use it. But when I pass 'msg' instead of 'this' the user gets a blank variable. I would like to pass more than just the msg - also an array of data passed in the ajax call and a jQuery object of the model box is what I would really like to do.

Below is the snippet - the function is inside of and called within the plugin; I just grouped some code into functions for organization/development purposes.

```
    // Submits the form inside of the model box
    // and calls the user hooks of onFormSuccess and
    // onFormFailure for ajax success and error
    function submitForm() {
        var URL = $('form',$contentNode).attr('action'), 
        method = $('form',$contentNode).attr('method'),
        data = $('form',$contentNode).formSerialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            type: method,
            data: data,
            success: function(msg) {
                // Doesn't work, but I would like it too
                //settings.onFormSuccess.call(msg, breakData(data) );
                // Does work
                settings.onFormSuccess.call(this);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                setings.onFormFailure.call(errorThrown);
            }
        });
        closeModel();
    }
```

Comment: tl dr; could you provide a shorter example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [`call` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). The first parameter determines what `this` will be inside the callback function itself. It is *not* passed as a parameter to the callback function.

To pass parameters to the callback you use the remaining parameters of `call`:

```
settings.onFormSuccess.call(thisArg, msg, dataArray);
```

The callback will then receive two parameters, and run with `this` pointing to `thisArg`:

```
function successHandler(msg, dataArray) {}
```

Another issue with your code is the value of `this` inside *your* success handler is meaningless. From what it looks like it will just point to the `window` object. So the callbacks you call will also be running with `this == window`.