# How does one raise an event in a jquery plugin, and consume it on the front-end?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to raise a couple of events with parameters within a jquery plugin, looked at similar questions, but cant seem to see what I am looking for? ANy basic examples out there?

Comment: reading this is basically what I need: ie a "callback": http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/making-a-jquery-plugin-truly-customizable I have tried creating an object to call-back but its seems to be undefined when referenced on the page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Plugin Development - passing parameters to user defined callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288199/jquery-plugin-development-passing-parameters-to-user-defined-callback-function)

Comment: I know these questions and answers were from a few years ago, but the answer here must have answered my question back then, a quick look shows different answers, so not sure what you want me to do here?

Comment: You had added an answer (which by now seems to have been deleted) to your own question with a link to another SO question where you found a solution to this question. I therefore flagged this question as a duplicate of the one you referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand well you want to provide some callbacks, being able to call them as

```
$(this).plugin({
    onInit: function(var) { alert(var) },
    onClick: function(var) { alert(var + '!') }
});
```

the way i do this is by adding an option 'onInit' to the plugin and call options.onInit(var1, var2, ...) inside the plugin in the place where i want it executed

```
$.fn.plugin = function(options) {
    var o = $.extend({}, $.fn.plugin.defaults, options);

    return this.each(
        function() {
            o.onInit('initializing...');

            $(this).bind('click', function(e) {
                onClick('clicked');
            });
        }
    );
}
```

now the former code will execute alert('initializing...'); on init and alert('clicked!'); on click

i am not sure this code follows any official syntax, but it works well

if you just want to bind some custom events it is simple as described in http://api.jquery.com/bind/, just

```
$(this).bind('customevent', function() {
    alert('hi');
});
```

then use

```
$(this).trigger('customevent');
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean this?

```
$('#theTarget').trigger('event-name', ['hello', 'world']);
```

I don't think I know what "consume it on the front-end" means ...

Comment: Thanks, will have a look...My terminology is a bit off there, I think I am looking for a "callback" from my jquery plugin which needs be run in the page (what I reffered to as the front-end)